# 2 TextField with 1 label in UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel, textfield

I am very new to programming
and I was wondering how I can put the information of 2 textField in 1 single label with a space between them.
Let's say put the first name and the last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two text fields and one label, and I guess you have the outlets of them like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

To put the text of two text fields inside the label do this

```
label.text = "\(field1.text) \(field2.text)"
```

I hope it will help.